# Trouble with curl and PHP

Tags: php, curl, sendwithus

I'm trying to work with an API. This is the example that's been provided to me in the documentation:

```
curl \
-X POST \
-u YOUR_API_KEY: \
-d '{
"email_id": "YOUR_EMAIL_ID",
"recipient": {
     "address": "some.one@email.com"
 }
}'
https://api.sendwithus.com/api/v1/send
```

This is my attempt at that:

```
$url = 'https://api.sendwithus.com/api/v1/send';
$user = 'my_api_key';

$params = array(
   'email_id' => 'my_email_id',
   'recipient' => array(
        'address' => 'my_email_address'
    )
);


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user. ':' . '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

When I var_dump $result, I get an empty string.

Do you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: the example uses json, and your version doesn't. you're sending normal `foo=bar` key/value pairs as if it was a normal form submission. you need json_encode() in the POSTFIELDS.

Answer (score 1):

Change you $params array into PHP Json_encode array like this:

$params = json_encode(you array);

Also here is the official SENDWITHUS API implementation code in PHP.

[SendWithUs PHP code](https://github.com/sendwithus/sendwithus_php)

Comment: I just tried that, but still got the same result. Here's the modified code I used:

    $params = json_encode(array(

'email_id' => 'my_api_key',

'recipient' => array(

'address' => 'my_email_address'

)

));

Comment: I'll give their client another shot. I was trying to avoid it, because the composer.json they provided seems to need some love and that's a whole other learning curve for me.